# How to optimize my code that is hitting run time limit?

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote this function to (1) Find a specific "control panel" sheet, (2) get specific cells for xls file to copy from, workbook to paste to and workbook's specific sheet. (3) From there, I open the specific source .xls file that is actually html code pasted onto a html file (4) From there, I get the tables from the html text (5) Paste those tables over into a google sheet.

Essentially, I am taking multiple .xls files and aggregating them together.  However, due to specific constraints, I am hitting the run time limit.

My attempts to fix this :

1. Try to reduce the amount of variables and logs I made
2. After I do "var values = html.match(/<table[\w\s\S]+?</table>/gi);", I tried to store it into a list. After that, I tried to make my "Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, idWhile);" but that ended up in an error
3. Currently researching other fixes

Here are the google sheets to reference the kind of "Control Panel" file I have to read the files I want to copy and where to put them. Also, the second sheet references the kind of '.xls' files I have which are actually .html files being stored in a .xls file.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t4FFBzRo2Qi7tfTfeZpnMdvp7U71kC7Nrt-8hT0OVMc/edit?usp=sharing

Script code:

```
function xlsCopy(){
  var spreadsheet = DriveApp.getFilesByName('testing_appscript_copying_2');
  var file = spreadsheet.next();
  var id = file.getId();
  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var controlPanelSheet = workbook.getSheetByName('ControlPanel');
  var rowIndex = 1;
 
  for (var i = 1 ; i < controlPanelSheet.getLastRow(); i++){
    //Reading cells for source and destination files
    fileName = controlPanelSheet.getRange(i+1, 2).getValues().toString();

    targetFileName = controlPanelSheet.getRange(i+1, 3).getValues().toString();

    targetSheetName = controlPanelSheet.getRange(i+1, 4).getValues().toString();

    //Searching the source files to find only ".csv" files
    phrase = '.csv';
    found = fileName.match(phrase);

    xlsPhrase = '.xls';
    xlsFound = fileName.match(xlsPhrase);
   
    if ('.xls' == xlsFound){

        var sourceFileName = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
        
        var sourceFileId = sourceFileName.getId()

        //Opening .xls file, getting all html text, parsing through for tables
        var html = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFileId).getBlob().getDataAsString();
        
        var values = html.match(/<table[\w\s\S]+?<\/table>/gi);

        //Put html tables to target spreadsheet
        var targetFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(targetFileName);
        
        while(targetFile.hasNext()) {
          var fi = targetFile.next();
          if(fi.getName() == targetFileName)
          {
            var idWhile=fi.getId();
          }
        }

        var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idWhile);

        var sheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
        
        var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
        
        //
      
        
        
        values.forEach(function(e) {
        
        var resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {html: true, data: e, coordinate: {sheetId: sheetId, rowIndex: rowIndex}}}]};
        rowIndex += e.match(/<tr[\w\s\S]+?<\/tr>/gi).length;
        Logger.log(rowIndex);
        
        Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, idWhile);
        Utilities.sleep(1000);
    })
      
    } else {
      Logger.log(fileName + "didn't run");
      
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I  just want to clarify, the sheet1 in your shared file is an example of your SourceFile.xls? You mentioned you are extracting tables in an html code? can you also include a sample expected output. (share a sample sourcefile.xls file as well)

Comment: Updated the google sheets. The "SourceFile.xls" is the html saved in an xls file. I am extracting the tables in the html code.

Finally, I shared a screenshot of the expected output + sample sourcefile.xls in the google sheets I linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing the tables one by one in your destination sheet in this code:

```
values.forEach(function(e) {
        
        var resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {html: true, data: e, coordinate: {sheetId: sheetId, rowIndex: rowIndex}}}]};
        rowIndex += e.match(/<tr[\w\s\S]+?<\/tr>/gi).length;
        Logger.log(rowIndex);
        
        Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, idWhile);
        Utilities.sleep(1000);
    })
```

You can combine them and write them only once:

```
var combinedTable = values.join(' ');
var resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {html: true, data: combinedTable, coordinate: {sheetId: sheetId, rowIndex: rowIndex}}}]};
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, idWhile);
```

> Note:
>
> I'm not so sure if you're goal is to append each source file tables when writing it in your destination sheet. But I noticed in your original code that if you write the `sourceFile_1` to `workbook1`, the `rowIndex` will retain the last rowIndex used `workbook1`. By the time `sourceFile_2` will be written to `workbook2`, the data will be written based on the last `rowIndex` value.

### (UPDATE):

If you want to append your source file data in your destination sheet you can refer to this code snippet:

```
        var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idWhile);
        Logger.log(destSpreadsheet.getName());
        var sheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
        var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();

        var range = targetSheetName+"!A1:A";
        Logger.log(range);
        var sheetValues = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(idWhile,range).values;

        if(sheetValues){
          //Sheet not empty
          //Add 1 blank row before appending new data
          rowIndex = sheetValues.length + 2;
        }else{
          //Sheet empty. Start row with row 1
          rowIndex = 1;
        }
        Logger.log("Start Row: "+rowIndex);
      
        var combinedTable = values.join(' ');
        var resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {html: true, data: combinedTable, coordinate: {sheetId: sheetId, rowIndex: rowIndex}}}]};
        Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, idWhile);
```

### What it does?

- Create a range to select destination sheet's Column A
- Use Sheets API to get column A content/values
- If the destination sheet is empty, it will return null. Else, count the length of column A content/values.

Comment: Thanks! joining the tables together as string really helped cut down. 

I read your note. I realized that was an issue yesterday. I tried to use "sheet.getLastRow()" after each loop but the issue is the batch updates do not seem to count as rows? It comes up as 0 every time.

Comment: Can you clarify your goal? do you intend to append tables in your workbook? example sourceFile_1 and sourceFile2 should be added in the same sheet in your workbook1?

Comment: Yes, I want to append tables in my workbook. I have a report with 20-30 xls files that go to 3-4 various files. I want to be able to just run this script and send the corresponding xls files to the destination workbooks. From there, I'll manually makes the necessary changes for each workbook.

----------------
My solution for the blank rows was to run a different script that deletes all rows with no values. Works fine for me tbh but if there is some way to improve this code, that would be awesome.

Comment: Noted on that. I'll try it on my end and see what i can do.